# Maximum number of $m\times n$ rectangles that fit in a $k \times k$ square

Tags: recreational-mathematics, packing-problem

I'm sure this has been asked before but I have searched for ages and can't quite find what I'm looking for. Here's the problem:

> Essentially what is the maximum possible number of rectangles of a given size $(m \times n)$ that will fit without overlapping in a given sized square ($k \times k$).

How can you tackle it?

Comment: Consider $\lfloor{\frac km}\rfloor$ and $\lfloor{\frac kn} \rfloor$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Well there's clearly a lower bound as Robert said below, but it's unclear whether there can be more rectangles that fit in the opposite orientation.

Answer (score 1):

In general, this kind of [packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems#Identical_rectangles_in_a_rectangle) is very difficult.  Of course there is an obvious upper bound
of $\lfloor k^2/(mn) \rfloor$ from consideration of areas, and a lower bound of $\lfloor k/m \rfloor \lfloor k/n \rfloor$. 
There can be a lot of room between these.

See e.g. [Recursive partitioning approach
for the Manufacturer's Pallet Loading Problem](http://lagrange.ime.usp.br/~lobato/packing/run/).