# uniform rectangle packing

Tags: geometry, optimization, packing-problem

I'm wondering if there is a formula or algorithm how many uniform rectangles of size $a\times b$ I can put in a square of size $c\times c$.

Does anyone have a hint for literature?

Comment: A necessary condition is that $N \times a \times b=c^2$ for a certain $N$, i.e., $c^2$ has to be divisible by $a \times b$. Is it a sufficient condition ? Probably, but I am not sure.

Comment: See slides 27 and following [here](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/transparencies/tilings.pdf) (obtained by using query "generalized domino tilings")

Comment: Packing problems are hard.  It doesn't do this one, concentrating on circles, but packomania.com will give you an idea that the configurations of interest are not always regular.  This one has more regularity because of the rectangles.

Comment: @JeanMarie:  I wish I had heard the talk.  Thanks.  I think OP doesn't mean to require that we cover the whole rectangle, just to find the maximum number of tiles that will fit.  The talk falsifies your condition by stating that $10 \times 15$ cannot be tiled by $1 \times 6$

Comment: See as well the reference given in the answer by Robert Israel [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3637016)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Ross is right, I didn't want to cover the whole rectangle but find the maximum number, c,a and b are already given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link that Jean Marie shared was what I was looking for